# How to install java plugin for firefox in Fedora 17 or 18

Tags: firefox, 64-bit, plugins, fedora-17, jre

I am running Fedora 17 64 Bit, I already installed firefox with the `yum install firefox`, and my firefox version is `22.0`

I am trying to install the java plugin for firefox.  But the instructions on how to do this are not working, I see some sites where Oracle is even apologizing for this.

How to install java plugin for firefox in Fedora 17 and 18?

Answer (score 2):

I spent too much time trying to get the java plugin 64 bit to work with firefox on Fedora 17. Something seems to be very wrong with the standard plugin setup.  These instructions worked for me, hopefully these will help others doing the same:

http://www.mjmwired.net/resources/mjm-fedora-f16.html#java

Written on 18 October 2011

The standard installation of Fedora should install OpenJDK (based on the Sun Java). However if not, it can be installed using YUM:

```
sudo yum install java-1.6.0-openjdk java-1.6.0-openjdk-plugin
```

With OpenJDK installed, Java application and Web applets should automatically work. Unfortunately some applets may not run properly and the OpenJDK might have some limitations. Majority of user should find OpenJDK perfect for everyday use.

Using Sun (Oracle) Java Instead

If you require Sun (Oracle) Java or if OpenJDK does not work properly, you can download Sun (Oracle) Java and use it in Fedora.

Download the Java package from: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html.

Under Java Platform, Standard Edition, Select: Download JRE (the JDK is for Java developers)

On the next page, accept the license agreement, then:

For 32-bit users: select "Linux x86"  `jre-7u1-linux-i586.rpm`

For 64-bit users: select "Linux x64"  `jre-7u1-linux-x64.rpm`

**To install:**

```
[mirandam@charon Download]$ sudo rpm -ivh jre-7u1-linux-i586.rpm
```

-OR-

```
[mirandam@charon Download]$ sudo rpm -ivh jre-7u1-linux-x64.rpm
```

When running the java command, Fedora will default to using OpenJDK. In order to use Sun Java, use the alternatives command.

To setup the Java runtime, perform the following (applies to both 32-bit and 64-bit users):

```
[mirandam@charon Download]$ sudo /usr/sbin/alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/java/default/bin/java 20000
```

**Setup the Mozilla/Firefox browser plugin.**

For 32-bit users:

```
sudo /usr/sbin/alternatives --install /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/libjavaplugin.so libjavaplugin.so /usr/java/default/lib/i386/libnpjp2.so 20000
```

For 64-bit users:

```
sudo /usr/sbin/alternatives --install /usr/lib64/mozilla/plugins/libjavaplugin.so libjavaplugin.so.x86_64 /usr/java/default/lib/amd64/libnpjp2.so 20000
```

You may need to restart Firefox to see the plugin take effect.

**Note: If you wish to switch back to OpenJDK you can run the following commands one by one to switch between the OpenJDK and Sun Java:**

```
[mirandam@charon ~]$ sudo /usr/sbin/alternatives --config java

[mirandam@charon ~]$ sudo /usr/sbin/alternatives --config libjavaplugin.so
```

(or for 64-bit)

```
[mirandam@charon ~]$ sudo /usr/sbin/alternatives --config libjavaplugin.so.x86_64
```

To Update: If you wish update the JRE package, simply download the newest RPM package and install it as above. You will NOT need to reset alternatives, as those settings should remain intact.